# Convert svg file to font angular 2 using webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I want to convert the .svg file to font file which i can use in my application.
I don't wan to use font awesome and because of this only i am using this.

I am very new to webpack and don't know how to do this. If anybody can explain this then it will be great help for me.

I have heard of `fontgen-loader` but after reading it i am not able to figure out from where to start.

Please give me some direction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use icomoon app to convert your svg files to fonts.
Keep in mind that font don't support multi color icons so you will need ro create component to support that(don't worry icommon already creates the html+css to support that).
Make sure that this is the best solution that you want to use,i'm currently trying to check inline svg option.